# python simple basic program on geeksforgeeks

Tags: python

Can anyone help me with the solution of this ?

Given a number N, print all the composite numbers less than or equal to N. The number should be printed in ascending order.

Input:
The first line contain an Integer T denoting the number of  test cases . Then T test cases follow. Each test case consist of an single integer N.

Output:
Print all the composite Number form 0 to N.

Constraints:

```
1 ≤ T ≤ 50
4 ≤ N ≤ 10000

Example:
Input:
2
10
6
Output:
4 6 8 9 10
4 6
```

My solution is as below :

```
def comp(n):
    for i in range (4,n+1):
        for j in range(2,i):
            if i % j == 0 :
                print(i)
                break

t = int(input(""))

while(t >=1 & t <= 50):
        for k in range(0,t):
            p = int(input(""))
            if(p >=4 & p <= 10000):
                comp(p)
```

but giving `EOFError` on `p = int(input(""))`

Comment: Where are you compiling this? Also, is this Python2 or 3?

Comment: why `while(t >=1 & t <= 50)` is `while` here?

Comment: @abhineet : its for mulitple test cases..and i am running it on geeksforgeeks website..

Comment: To check for multiple test cases you have, `for k in range(0,t):`. The first line, it should just check if the given `t` is valid or not, i.e., `if(t >=1 & t <= 50)`, same as you have done for `p`. Keeping `t` in `while` will result in infinite loop as the value of `t` is non-decrementing & non-incrementing.

Comment: http://ideone.com/VffJlX

Comment: @Abhineet `if` conditions are unnecessary for this problem, those are mere input constraints which are well within standard range.

Comment: @dust0x:: NO, the input constraint SHOULD be verified and validated in the code as soon the input is consumed. The constraints are never MERE.

Comment: @Abhineet I just don't see a point in adding complexity in solutions to trivial problems, but you're right - that is the best practice.

Comment: @dust0x:: Constraints are not complexities. They are there, so that you can validate the given input. If the input ranges out of bound, then you will have complexity given there is no constraint checking.

Comment: @dust0x:: Are you sure that it don't solve the problem? :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124614/discussion-between-abhineet-and-dust0x).

Comment: If you got your solution, then kindly accept the most accurate solution.

Comment: Smh, GeeksForGeeks.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you are providing lesser input values than required. Your program is expecting more input's than you actually provided.

if you are using a pipe to send data to stdin of the script then make sure each input is sent in a newline as shown below.

```
   time echo -e "2\n'3 4 5 6 7'\n3" | python sample.py
```

Comment: You are right that the program is expecting more inputs. It doesn't mean that we have to provide that many inputs to the code. There is a logical error in the code part because of which, the code is expecting more inputs.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit here is the `while` loop instead of `if`. As, the `t` is a constant value, the `while` loop will never end and thus, `p = int(input(""))` will get executed more than the required times. Hence, `EOFError` on `p = int(input(""))`.

Answer (score -2):

A simple solution using recursion.

```
def check_prime(n):
    for i in range(2,int(math.sqrt(n))+1):
        if(n%i==0):
            return 0
    return 1

def print_composite(n):
    if(n<5):
        print(n),
        return
    print_composite(n-1)
    if(check_prime(n)==0):
        print(n),
        return
```

Sample outputs from my terminal

```
>>> print_composite(10)
4 6 8 9 10
>>> print_composite(6)
4 6
>>> print_composite(16)
4 6 8 9 10 12 14 15 16
```

Comment: This solution doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: @Abhineet so what, i gave him a precise solution... i know it's not an answer, thanks for the downvote

Comment: You can guide OP with all the GFG problems, but kindly refrain from doing this on SO platform. You can ask for his personal mail/number and start there. Don't get offended. We are all here to solve problems but no spoon feeding.

Comment: The best way to remove the downvote is to edit the answer, so that it provides a better explanation and solution to the OP question.